Error connecting to the postgresql NestJS database
please help me. I have a database 'moneymanager' it has an 'auth' scheme. I connect to the database like this:
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {TypeOrmModule as NestTypeOrmModule} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as process from "process";

@Module({
    imports: [
        NestTypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: 'postgres',
            host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
            port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
            username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
            password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
            entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
            synchronize: true,
            migrationsRun: false
        })
    ],
})

export class TypeOrmModule {
} 

But he writes me this error:
 [Nest] 33320  - 09/09/2024, 11:29:05 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] 
    AggregateError
        at __node_internal_ (node:internal/errors:174:15)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)

I want to use synchronize: true to develop a project. synchronize: false works fine
I want to use synchronize: true to develop a project. synchronize: false works fine

do you have a git repo for this
